# jQuery: sorting of multiple tables based on lowestvalue(marks),

Tags: jquery

The table is like,How To sorting a table and based on lowestvalue(marks), i done like the following first i want to get the value and second i get the next value and third step is i want to compare the two values.like following,any one can help me please,thankyou

```
<tab>$(function(){
   var table = <tab>$('#one');
   var sortMarks = function(a,b)
   {
       var aVal = Number(<tab>$(a).find('a.marks').each.text());
       var bVal = Number(<tab>$(b).find('a.marks').each.text());
       return aVal > bVal ? 1 : -1;
   };
   table.find('tr').sort(sortMarks).appendTo(table); // sort       
});
<html>
    <title></title>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table id="one" class="tabl" cellspacing="0" >
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td><input class="dep" type="radio" name="depart"></td>
      <td><a class="marks">500</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table> 
    <table id="one" class="tabl" cellspacing="0" >
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td><input class="dep" type="radio" name="depart"></td>
      <td><a class="marks">200</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="one" class="tabl" cellspacing="0" >
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td><input class="dep" type="radio" name="depart"></td>
      <td><a class="marks">300</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="one" class="tabl" cellspacing="0" >
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td><input class="dep" type="radio" name="depart"></td>
      <td><a class="marks">400</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure u parse values, as they will all be strings, secondly,

demo here
use jquery table sorter plugin , http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

and download here
http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download